# SignalR not Responding when Hosted out side of LAN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr

I have implemented the Stock Tracker Example and the Chat example in my LAN environment and everything is working fine, within the LAN I hosted it on a Windows Server 2008 within IIS as a  MVC 4 app with no problems.

I then moved the App to a replica server inside a DMZ which is accessible globally, I tried running the App within the LAN and the Tracker and the Chat became unresponsive. I Also tried doing this from a Samsung Galaxy S3, this site was responsing but triggering the Stock Tracker nothing happens.

Within our LAN it accesses public sites using a NAT, is it possible to use SignalR in this scenario?

If so is there any firewall exceptions I need to make?
Also, is there any IIS configuration elements I need to consider?

This is the first time looking at SignalR and I can't seem to find examples of such setups.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Try to access <URL>/signalr/hubs. You should get javascript code for the hubs or an exception in case you have configured something wrong.
From browser, hit F12 to open JavaScript Developer Console to see if SignalR is throwing any error. You need to enable signalr client logging first.

Comment: Tried both of those tricks but made no difference. I am starting think it is an environment issue as I have deplyed to it a new server in the dmz and it is now working fine. only difference is I installed MVC via nuget into the project rather than installing mvc into the GAC

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest MVC Libraries via Nuget fixed this. Previously Installed MVC 3 manually on the server via exe downloaded from MS downloads